# Can i have the same path for two classes in Rest Api?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

Is it possible to define same path for two classes?

```
@Path("/resource")    
public class ResourceA{
..
..
}

@Path("/resource")
public class ResourceB(){
..
..
}
```

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: I did not try this sample,

Comment: Your code is not complete, you must have some methods. What happens if you use identical `@Path` annotations *on classes*? What happens if you use them on *methods*? Try!

Comment: Take a look at chapter "3.7 Matching Requests to Resource Methods" of [the JAX-RS Specification](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/sources/spec/show).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isn't possible, you have that to separate with the methods.

Example:

```
@Path("/resource")    
public class Resource{

    @Path("/A")
    public void resourceA(){
      ...
    }
    @Path("/B")
    public void resourceB(){
      ...
    }
 ..
}
```

You can access resourceA with the url "/resource/A" and resourceB with "/resource/B".

I hope this help.

Comment: (minus one)- Sorry but this is wrong. [It _is_ possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31306828/2587435)

Answer (score 10):

It **is** possible. See the [JAX-RS Spec 3.7.2 Request Matching](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html). In layman's terms, the spec states that all matching root resource classes are put into a set, then all the matching methods from those classes are put into a set. Then sorted. So if the resource class level `@Path`s are the same, they will both be put into the set for further processing

You can easily test this out, as I have done below (with [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html))

```
public class SamePathTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Test
    public void testSamePaths() {
        String xml = target("resource").request()
                .accept("application/xml").get(String.class);
        assertEquals("XML", xml);
        String json = target("resource").request()
                .accept("application/json").get(String.class);
        assertEquals("JSON", json);
    }

    @Path("resource")
    public static class XmlResource {
        @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public String getXml() { return "XML"; }
    }

    @Path("resource")
    public static class JsonResource {
        @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getJson() { return "JSON"; }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(XmlResource.class, JsonResource.class);
    }
}
```